# Node.js limitations of port and number

Tags: node.js

Why can't I use port 80 in node.js?  Also what are the rules of ports and ip addresses when I call the listen function in node.js.  which ones are allowed and why?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Yo');

}).listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run Node.js on port 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 80 is protected, you need to be root to use it:

```
sudo node script.js
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also [forward port 80 to above-1024 port using iptables or use authbind](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/386)

Comment: I used iptables with much happiness