# How to start node.js on port 80 on a linux server?

Tags: linux, node.js, port

When I try to start node on port 80, the error tells me that the port is in use. I imagine that's Apache.

What is the proper way to "take over" port 80, and keep it that way after a server restart?

(Linux xxxx.*_*_.com 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 14 09:42:28 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use ip tables to map port 80 to 8000

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

to make it permanent

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

and add

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

to your /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: can you explain a little what's going on with the last two commands? after reboot, i can't seem to connect to the server from the browser

Comment: it restores iptable rules on reboot, otherwise the iptables rule would just last until you reboot your server. have your node app listen on port 8000.

Comment: Can changing iptables in that fashion make it impossible to connect to the server via ssh? I've done it, rebooted via /sbin/reboot and now the server appears dead - times out on connection

Comment: yea if you misconfigured your /etc/network/interface file, the interface won't come up again. test it with ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0, so you won't lock yourself out.

Comment: I've added the pre-up line line of interface file. Rebooted, server started fine. Rebooted again, dead. Server issue unrelated to iptables?

Comment: well if it was still working after the reboot the interface file should be okay, otherwise the server would have been unresponsive after the first reboot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37059/discussion-between-supernova-and-dsp-099)

Answer (score 2):

To take over port 80 when another process is listening on it, you must kill the process (or somehow tell it to stop listening). To ensure that Apache doesn't try to listen on port 80 again the next time it starts, you need to edit its configuration or prevent it from starting up.

To see which process is listening on port 80, run `sudo netstat -ntap` and look for the row with `Local Address` ending in port `:80`. The PID of the process (and the name) is in the far right column.

Answer (score 1):

you can use node.js with node-http-proxy check this link [How to use vhosts alongside node-http-proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368794/how-to-use-vhosts-alongside-node-http-proxy/9645091#9645091) and 
[How do I run Node.js on port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80)

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1):

A constantly running unused apache maybe a security hole, in any case no sense in running unused services.

On the chance you're on ubuntu, this what I used..

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can access port 80 once you stop the service currently using it.**

In your case, follow these steps:

1) Use `systemctl` to stop apache2:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

2) Check apache2 status:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

Or just by entering `http://localhost` in your browser. If you get an error, you are good to go.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

3) Now start your NodeJS server on port 80.

4) You can access your server at `http://localhost`

### UPDATE

*If you are seeing errors on your console, try `node` preceding with `sudo`
For eg. `sudo node server.js`*

Here are the errors

```
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1349:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1407:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1495:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abdus/Desktop/voice-recognition/test.js:7:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
```

Comment: Use of NGINX reverse-proxy will be a better choice, IMO.