# localhost forward localhost:8080/blah in tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, redirect, tomcat6, forward

I have a web application this is running on tomcat and port 8080. I can not use 80 port because i don't have root priviliges linux machine. I want to do that when i print explorer tab  [http://localhost], i want to open this application  [http://localhost:8080/blah] is it possible? My server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="8443" 
server="Sunucu" 
allowTrace="false" />
```

if possible how can i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To use `http://hostname/` without a port the server needs to bind to port 80. On Linux you need root karma to do that. You state you don't have root karma so there is no way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Linux OS doesn't allow ports less than 1024 for non root user. Hence you either you need to run your tomcat server in root user not as tomcat user(This is a serious security issue, giving root access). Or map port 8080 to 80. You can find how to configure iptable to route port in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703725/how-to-start-node-js-on-port-80-on-a-linux-server)