# configure apache2 for node.js in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, apache, debugging, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

i have a website running on, let's say, `example.com` that uses apache. i'm writing an app in node.js that i would like to be accessed through `example.com/app`, and have my node.js server think that `example.com/app` is `/` and `example.com/app/users` is `/users`. i tried to do this via `ProxyPass` using some tutorial i found online, but that doesn't quite give me exactly what i'm looking for (unless i don't have it set up right).

here's the `ProxyPass` I'm using:

```
ProxyPass /app/ http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

but when I go to `example.com/app/users` my node server thinks that i'm trying to access `//users` which obviously throws a `404`. any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use vhosts alongside node-http-proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368794/how-to-use-vhosts-alongside-node-http-proxy)