# A proxy in a virtual host form an external ip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy, virtualhost

So I am having three `node` apps on the same server and they are all started to different localhost's ports. With that I am trying to do kind of a router that make a proxy for every apps and then put this proxy in a virtual host. Currently I am testing this on my local network but it will be on a "real" server in the future.

Just to make an exemple, my router is on `0.0.0.0:3000` and one of my apps is on `0.0.0.0:3001`. So here is how it looks like if I try to make a proxy to the app on the router :

```js
app.use('/*', proxy({ target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3001', changeOrigin: true }));
```

It works when I am going on `http://localhost:3000`. But it is not in a virtual host, so here it is :

```js
app.use('/*', 
  vhost('test.*', proxy({ target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3001', changeOrigin: true }))
);
```

It still works but only on `http://test.localhost:3000`.

If I try to access it via my IP (`mydomain.com` is mapped to my IP in my `hosts` file, you can see it down bellow) : `http://test.mydomain.com` express return me `Cannot GET /`. And even on `mydomain.com` it works well without the virtual host.

Here is my `hosts` file (I am not sure if it is safe to share this IP so I am masking a part of it) :

```
192.168.*.*:3000 mydomain.com
```

Packages I use : [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware), [vhost](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost), [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express).

---

My final question is : how could I make this virtual host works on another IP / domain than `localhost` ?

**UPDATE :**

I don't know if this information can be usefull, but even if I put `www.google.com` in my proxy **with the virtual host**, it doesn't works.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368794/how-to-use-vhosts-alongside-node-http-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

I give up the idea of doing it with `node`, it was creating too much problems.
I ended up with an nginx reverse proxy. After some research it seems like a reverse proxy was what I wanted to do, and it worked, so good fit.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_inverse