# How to change value of process.env.PORT in node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I'd like to change the value of `process.env.PORT`, how can I do this?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

For just one run (from the unix shell prompt):

```
$ PORT=1234 node app.js
```

More permanently:

```
$ export PORT=1234
$ node app.js
```

In [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
set PORT=1234
```

In Windows [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx):

```
$env:PORT = 1234
```

Comment: For documentation sake, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776899(v=vs.85).aspx for windows users

Comment: Also for Powershell, it's `$env:PORT = 80` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Comment: `VAR_1=value VAR_2=11827 node` -> simply use a space to use more than one variable on the same command

Answer (score 18):

You can use cross platform solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

```
$ cross-env PORT=1234
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution. There's way too much margin for error with the different terminals. I spent like 40 minutes until I found `cross-env` abstracts this problem away and just works.

Answer (score 8):

use the below command to set the port number in node process while running node JS programme:

```
set PORT =3000 && node file_name.js
```

The set port can be accessed in the code as

```
process.env.PORT
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Per @sshow's comment, if you're trying to run your node app on port 80, the below is not the best way to do it. Here's a better answer: [How do I run Node.js on port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80/27805105#27805105)

**Original Answer:**

If you want to do this to run on port 80 (or want to set the env variable **more permanently**),

1. Open up your bash profile
   `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add the environment variable to the file `export PORT=80`
3. Open up the sudoers config file `sudo visudo`
4. Add the following line to the file exactly as so `Defaults        env_keep +="PORT"`

Now when you run `sudo node app.js` it should work as desired.

Comment: Running your node scripts as root (sudo) is not recommended. Use `sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`, and listen on port 8080 instead. http://stigok.tumblr.com/post/139320914543/nodejs-http-listen-port-80-without-sudo-using

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've linked to a better discussion (that I also answered, *disclaimer*) and learned after initially using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
PORT=2222 node-dev app.js
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.