# How to export env variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, environment-variables

I like my `node.js` so much, that I want to use it is my `bash` start up script `~/.bashrc`, but I do not know how to export variable.

Currently I have to use this approach:

```
export PS1=`node ~/PS1.js`
export PS2=`node ~/PS2.js`
export PATH=`node ~/PATH.js`
```

instead I want `.bashrc` look have

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
//do something, define functions
export_var('PS1', PS1())
export_var('PS2', PS2())
export_var('PATH', generatePATH())
```

`process.env.PATH = something` does not *export*, only sets for the currently executing process, which is node itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change value of process.env.PORT in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333221/how-to-change-value-of-process-env-port-in-node-js)

Comment: try to use "#." as the 1st line and keep the first block of code

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto, you do not understand the question and are trying to close it instead? I need to change the variable from inside node.js and let the parent process keep it. The question you are referring to is about changing PORT variable before the node.js starts.

Comment: You need get the text? You need open process manually inside your main process? Use ' instead ` on .bashrc exports and get the commands as string.

Comment: @GabrielBiga, I do not need to get the text of the variable, I need to set it persistently, this is called "export variable" in Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node.js will run in an separate process which gets a copy of the environment. You cannot change the environment of you parent process (the one executing .bashrc).

But the following question has an answer for you:
[Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell)

You can write a new script file from within node.js and call it via `source`.

Comment: Could you add a code example for this as I don't understand how I can source a node.js script: "You can write a new script file from within node.js and call it via source."

Comment: How it cal work? Script should be executed in the parent shell, but this is not possible.

Answer (score 12):

One possible way is to use JS to print out the export statements, then in shell to use eval to evaluate it in the current shell.

e.g. test.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('export A=40; export B=10');
```

In the shell:

```sh
eval `./test.js`
echo $A
```

Comment: This was simple and clean magic! For those using yarn, use `yarn --silent <script>` when running your command.

Comment: super clean solution. works great. thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

In my case it works:

```
const exportVar = (name, value) => {
    process.env[name] = value;
};

exportVar("NODE_ENV", "test");
```

But also in some cases it can be useful to play with [exec (or spawn)](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

execSync("NODE_ENV=test && echo $NODE_ENV", {
    stdio: 'inherit',
});
```