# Custom Port on VorlonJS

Tags: javascript, remote-debugging, livereload

I try to use [VorlonJS](http://vorlonjs.com/) to debug on remote devices. However it uses the Port 1337 which I am using for LiveReload to my Grunt Tasks. I can configure it Grunt Side but in the Vorlon Side Is there any options? I couldn't see it on [Docs](http://vorlonjs.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no options as `vorlon --port=1234`
But, We [can](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs/issues/21) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333312/2007333);

unix shell:
`$ PORT=1234`

More permanently:
`$ export PORT=1234`

In Windows:
`set PORT=1234`

In Windows PowerShell:
`$ env:PORT=1234`