# Change PORT for process.env.PORT in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, port

For an Express App, I need to temporarily change `PORT` for my App:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port)
```

I have already read the following StackOverflow question but it is not working for me:

[How to change value of process.env.PORT in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333221/how-to-change-value-of-process-env-port-in-node-js)

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Something like `PORT=8081 node app.js` or just `export PORT=8081` It's usual shell environment

Comment: Thanks vp_arth, I was able to figure out my problem , something in my environment was already listening to my tested port no.