# dynamicly import modules based on webpack config or cli params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, webpack

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically import modules in JS react components based on parameters from a webpack configuration.

So that `THEME_PATH` from
`import ./theme/{THEME_NAME}/indes.less`

Would be dynamically replaced through a webpack param or CLI parameters on webpack build.

Any suggestions or hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin):

*webpack config:*

```
   plugins: [
        ...
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __THEME__: '"' + process.env.THEME.toString() + '"'
        })
    ]
```

*and in your code:*

```
require('./theme/' + __THEME__ + '/index.less')
```

You can pass `THEME` [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333221/how-to-change-value-of-process-env-port-in-node-js) (depends on your OS and shell).

Also you can pass prameters from [cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js) instead of using `process.env`.

---

If you importing theme in less file, not js:

*less file:*

```
@import "theme/@{THEME}/index.less";
```

*webpack config (less-loader):*

```
'!less?{"modifyVars":{"THEME":"' + process.env.THEME + '"}}'
```

Comment: Great. This solved my problem. An additional note to this is that
require('./theme/' + __THEME__ + '/index.less') works fine
but 
import '../theme/' + __THEME__ + '/index.less'
will fail

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible also with `import` syntax? I'm using `import` everywhere and would have to use `require` just in a single place.

Comment: You cant use `import` with variables, so it is not possible.