# stripping port number from domain in aws server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

http://www.basicspace.org:5000/#/

Here is my url, I want to run the app just on the http://www.basicspace.org without the port number. I have seen lots of tutorials but none got into my head so asking it here for better solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run Node.js on port 80?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80)

Comment: you can also reverse proxy, use iptables, or use ELB. But if you're running node on a single EC2 and this is over your head, use Elastic Beanstalk or Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a single EC2 Instance which is running NodeJS then. If it listens behind and ELB, then PORT source and destination to be configured in ELB.

```
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  response.write('Hello World');
  response.end();
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Could you check - is the Security Group policy for PORT 80 - TCP opened for 0.0.0.0/0