# Click to deploy MEAN Stack on Google Compute Engine can not direct access app

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean-stack

I have used the Click to deploy MEAN Stack on Google Cloud Compute Engine. 
After deployment I can via SSH view the index.html on my local macbook. 
But trying to take a look at it with direct access will not work. I have checked for "Allow HTTP traffic".

Machine: n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.8 GB memory)

Zone: europe-west1-d

External IP: 104.155.23.82:3000

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because enabling the "Allow HTTP/S Traffic" only opens port 80/443 in the firewall, not to port 3000 which is where node and MEAN listen to by default.

If you want to change the stack to listen on port 80 or 443, here are some options:  [How do I run Node.js on port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80)

Comment: My mistake. I do use port 3000. Did you try to open 104.155.23.82:3000?

Comment: And your right. I forgotten to add a firewall rule for port 3000. 
Add new firewall rule, give it a name, ip-range (0.0.0.0/0) and tcp:3000.
Thanks a lot!