# Linuxbrew Nodejs - Bind to port 80

Tags: node.js, port, linuxbrew

I want to solve the same problem which has been described in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80).

Therefore I wanted to execute the following command:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /home/username/.linuxbrew/bin/node
```

This produced the error:

```
Failed to set capabilities on file `/home/username/.linuxbrew/bin/node' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file
```

Does this happen because the foldername is **.linuxbrew** and if yes how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked if its symlinked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because you are trying to run that on a symlink. Try running this instead:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep $(readlink -f ~username/.linuxbrew/node)
```

Comment: Yes you were right. I was too stupid to recognize that /home/username/.linuxbrew/bin/node was a symlink. Thanks for the help.