# Node application cannot start on port 80 unless different node version

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2, nvm

I have a node.js Express backend API application and we use yarn and pm2.

I know the version has been upgraded from node 11 to node 12 so I installed 12 using `nvm install 12`

When I update the sourcecode via git and do `yarn start`, there is an error saying it does not have the permission to run the application on port 80. Just out of curiosity I switched back to node 11 using nvm, and run `yarn start` without changing any source code or config, and the application started.

Does anyone has pointers as to why Node 12 does not seem to have permission required to start a service on port 80 , while node 11 could?

If this is related to the way I installed node 12 using `nvm install 12`, can someone point me to the right resources where I can understand more about nvm's encapsulation and permission settings ? thanks.

EDIT :
As a workaround as Lawrence suggested, I reroute it to run on 8080. Back to the core of the question, why does Node 11 has permission , but Node 12 does not have the permission required to run on port 80?

Comment: it shouldn't have worked on 11, maybe you installed node 11 with root, ports below 1024 are privileged and always have been and require root user to run a service on them, you should look into installing nginx and forwarding 80 to 8080 or such, its never a good idea to do `sudo node index.js` etc to overcome this issue or run node as root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run Node.js on port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109089/how-do-i-run-node-js-on-port-80)

Comment: Yes I do understand it is common to do it via iptable and route 8080 to 80 (or some other ports). I also understand what worked in 11 should not worked in 12 since its a major version change. But I am trying to figure out why was it complaining about permission in the first place.